# Composer not working on AWS Ubuntu server, locally works fine

Tags: symfony-1.4, php, composer-php

Composer install command works fine locally on my computer:

- Loading composer repositories with package information
- Installing dependencies from lock file
- Nothing to install or update
- Generating autoload files

When I connect via ssh to the ubuntu server, and run the same command I get this.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Composer\Installers\Installer' not found in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer/InstallerInstaller.php on line 102

Fatal error: Class 'Composer\Installers\Installer' not found in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer/InstallerInstaller.php on line 102
```

I followed the instructions here for both machines:
https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/README.md

I am missing some dependencies here? I can't figure out why that error.

**Edit**: Here is the .json (project is symfony 1.4, adding tags as well)

```
{
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "require"     : {
    "snappy/sfSnappyPlugin": "*"
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "https://github.com/FloranBrutel/sfSnappyPlugin.git"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Edit2**: The output of the php -v on the AWS server

```
PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Sep 12 2012 18:59:41) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

On my machine I have:

```
PHP 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.9 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Sep 12 2012 19:00:27) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2011 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2011 Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v2.1.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2010, by Derick Rethans
```

Comment: Can you put your composer.json so I can try and reproduce?

Comment: What's the output of `php -v` ?

Comment: I am really clueless. Shouldnt it be looking for Composer\Installer\InstallerInstaller instead of Composer\Installers\Installer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have managed to replicate your problem.  Within the directory you are running composer, you should have a path like so:

```
vendor/composer/installers/src/Composer/Installers
```

and within this directory there should exist an `Installer.php` file.  I managed to get the same error you are getting by deleting that one file.

So I believe a solution would be to simply completely remove your `vendor` and `plugins` directories and try running `composer install` again, forcing the complete re-download of all the vendors in your `composer.json`.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, i never thought the problem was with the vendor folder. Why was that file deleted on the first place? It is not ignored on git.

Comment: You should ignore the `vendor` directory. But anyway, it could simply be that you were using an old version of composer and the files have moved since. Composer is not stable yet, and it move fast.

Comment: I had the same problem. So what I did was I first renamed the composer folder in my Vendor folder. Once this was correct, I removed the original folder. I was using CakePHP hence this was a Vendor folder

Answer (score 1):

What are the exact commands you run?

What you should do:

- run `rm -rf vendor/*` to erase all possible composer data (it use vendor/.composer as a cache)
- run `composer self-update` to update Composer to it latest. Does this works?
- try `composer -V`
- make sure you have openSsl on the server (as you are requiring over https)
- switch APC to false on the cli `apc.enable_cli=0`

Comment: While your answer had the step to solve my problem (rm -rf vendor/*), i accepted the other one because it was more specific to my problem.